# jQuery with dropdown menu for Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am creating a basic dropdown menu using jQuery 1.10. It doesn't work on IE8. How can I fix this?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZP9M/)**

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".urun").hover(function(){
        $("ul").slideDown(250);
        $("ul").mouseleave(function(){
            $("ul").slideUp(200);
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://blog.moovweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/stackoverflow-logo.png" alt="" class="urun"/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">321</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">213</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">312</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">331</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what's your IE version?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .urun
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
        ul
        {
            list-style: none;
            display: none;
        }
        ul li
        {
            padding: 5px;
            width: 150px;
        }
        ul li:hover
        {
            background: #777;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://blog.moovweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/stackoverflow-logo.png"
        alt="" class="urun" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">321</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">213</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">312</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">331</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".urun").hover(function () {
                $("ul").slideDown(250);
                $("ul").mouseleave(function () {
                    $("ul").slideUp(200);
                });
            });
        });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason jsfiddle's snippets doesn't seem to work properly on ie8 when you use jQuery 1.10. I've added your example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/eyexov/5 - it works just fine there.

Hover can handle two functions in this way:

```
$(element).hover(function() {
    // your "mouseenter" event
}, function() {
    // your "mouseleave" event
});
```

You just used in in a wrong way. Check [hover's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) page for more info.

Comment: It doesn't work on jsfiddle, but it generally works. Check this example: http://jsbin.com/eyexov/2

Comment: Are you try, first hover image after over ul. Know, like I said

Comment: @fthmad9 - If you meant that menu hides when you point the cursor on the area next to the menu, then here's a quick fix - you can for example wrap the image and menu with another container: http://jsbin.com/eyexov/5.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, change only the version of the jquery that you have in FIDDLE to for example 1.9.1.

Using .hover function is the same that

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

so you have a mix of the two, you should change your function hover to this:

```
$(".urun").hover(
function () {
    $("ul").slideDown(250);
},

function () {
    $("ul").slideUp(200);
});
```

**EDIT:**

I think that this is a problem using jquery version 1.10.1, if you use 1.10.0 works fine..

Comment: If fthmad9 wants to use 1.10 specifically, suggestion to change library's version doesn't help much.